# PHP mailer Character encoding issue

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmailer

I m facing some character encoding issues like this:

```
D\\\'Huison-Longueville RÃ©fÃ©rence
```

Original Text was :

```
D'Huison-Longueville Référence
```

Here is my PHP Mailer script:

```
                 $mail = new PHPMailer();
                 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                 $mail->IsMail();
                 $mail->Subject = $subject;
                 $mail->IsHTML(true);
                 $mail->Body = $email_body;
                 $mail->From='support@xyz.com';
                 $mail->FromName= "Support Team";
                 $mail->AddAddress($toEmail);
                 $mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The charset was not being changed although I was specifying the new one like you with:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Since you use "IsMail" you have to go to the folder where class.phpmailer.php resides (generally in the same folder as the main phpmailer.php file) and edit it. There you will see the default values for the mail and you will see that it is set to "ISO-8859-1".

Change

```
public $CharSet = 'ISO-8859-1';
```

to

```
public $CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Change it to "UTF-8" or any other charset you want.